# Hibernate One to Many Mapping is trying to update mapping column to null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am using below mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestOrder implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderid", updatable = false)
    protected Long orderId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id_fk")
    private List<TestDetails> details;

//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="test_details")
public class TestDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    //Generator
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name="order_id_fk", updatable = false)
    private Long orderId;
//getters and setters
}
```

When I update/insert the data, it's trying to update the `order_id_fk` to null

```
SQL [update test_details set order_id_fk'='null where order_id_fk'='? and id'='?]; constraint [null];
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Updating/Inserting using Spring Integration

```
<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway entity-class="com.aaaa.TestOrder" entity-manager-factory="myEntityManagerFactory" persist-mode="MERGE">
    <int-jpa:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: Could you paste the code DAO please ?

Comment: @Pracede, I am using spring integration to insert/update. updated op

Comment: Did you set TestOrder and it attribute details before saving or updating ?

Comment: @Pracede, yes. surprisingly its inserting data first as expected. but after that it's trying execute this update query

Comment: Wheres @ManyToOne annotation and `mappedBy` ?

Comment: Are you saying that you set the order_id_fk manually, still the hibernate is changing it to null?

Comment: @Zeus, I am not setting it manually. Hibernate, for no reason, trying to update with null value. if you look at query also, trying to select record based on order_id_fk and setting the same with null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to fetch values of `TestDetails` entity eagerly.

Just modify in your annotation with,

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="testOrder", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: any reason to use `mappedBy` instead of `Join Column`. because `Test Order` should be the owner and `TestDetails` has foreign key column [order_id_fk] in its schema

Comment: one more doubt, if I add `mappedBy`, I have to add `TestOrder` property to `TestDetails` with `ManyToOne` relation. is it mandatory to have bi-directional relation as I expect not to be.

Comment: if you used mapped by then hibernate will know which entity values need to fetch.

Comment: agree. But it needs mapping from other side too [Test_details]. just to increase my knowledge, is it should be like this or my initial approach is flawed?

Comment: here no need to join column because with reference of model object you will get the list of testDetails. Just make sure in TestDetails ManyToOne relationship is assign with TestOrder. so remove JoinColumn of testDetails from TestOrder and change it to only oneToMany relationship.

Answer (score 4):

I ran your code and it works correctly (when added `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to both IDs).

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
TestOrder to = new TestOrder();
TestDetails td1 = new TestDetails();
TestDetails td2 = new TestDetails();
TestDetails td3 = new TestDetails();
to.setDetails(Arrays.asList(new TestDetails[] {td1, td2, td3}));
em.persist(to);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

what results in following sqls:

```
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: insert into test (orderid) values (1) 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: insert into test_details (order_id_fk, id) values (NULL, 2) 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: insert into test_details (order_id_fk, id) values (NULL, 3) 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: insert into test_details (order_id_fk, id) values (NULL, 4) 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: update test_details set order_id_fk=1 where id=2 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: update test_details set order_id_fk=1 where id=3 
[03/07/14 10:03:30]  INFO jdbc.sqlonly: update test_details set order_id_fk=1 where id=4
```

So, if the code you posted is the code which you compile then TestOrder entity is not able to generate its ID (lack of `@GeneratedValue` annotation).

In case of database generating IDs (i.e. using autonumbering) for this entity, you should set `@GeneratedValue` to `IDENTITY` to let your jpa provider know that it must reread inserted row afterwards. If jpa provider fails to reread id, it updates test_details order_id_fk column with null.

PS. Why didn't you set many-to-one relationship at TestDetails side?

Comment: thanks for such efforts. I will check on that and update you.  Regarding many to one from TestDetails, is it necessary? Because I do see some cyclic dependency and issues with my knowledge in Hibernate :)

Comment: It is not necessary and will cause you to remember to update both sides of relationship (`testOrder.setDetails(testDetails); testDetails.setOrder(testOrder)`). But it will allow you to simply navigate from testDetails instance to testOrder one (by `testDetails.getOrder()`). You probably got cyclic dependency errors   because one of bidirectional relationship side should be inverse (this one which doesn't have column with foreign key). Inverse side can be marked by adding `mappedBy` attribute in your `@OneToMany` annotation.

Comment: I have gone through huge code base and found that, it's getting the `order_id` from other table `temp_order`. In short, first order created in `temp_order` table and the same will be used as `id` in `order` table

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the entity like below. As far as I remember, if you are trying to set the foreign key of a column this works best.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_details")
public class TestDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    //Generator
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name="order_id_fk", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private TestOrder orderId;
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I think you have to try it again:) that is the proper way to get it done.